# Pass array through ajax (not working)

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, post

I have an array named "bulk" that looks like this:

```
bulk['A']['country'] = 'country';
bulk['B']['country'] = 'country2';
bulk['B']['otherdata'] = 'Data';
```

So, it's like a multidimensional array... I'm passing it trough ajax like this:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url:"SaveFields.php",
        dataType:'json',
        data:bulk,
        success:UpdatePoints,
        error:function()
        {
            console.log('Falló el ajax, presione Control+F5');
        }

    });
```

BUT, it's not being received on the php post! I'm doing a printr and the POST is empty...

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

HOWEVER, if I try to pass any other data, any other array... the data is received and the post is printed!
There's something obviously wrong with the "bulk" array but I can't understand what... any tips? any clues?

the bulk receives data from fields like this:

```
bulk[bloque_nombre]['country'] = campos[0].val();
bulk[bloque_nombre]['name'] = campos[1].val();
bulk[bloque_nombre]['title'] = campos[2].val();
bulk[bloque_nombre]['area'] = campos[4].val();
bulk[bloque_nombre]['city'] = campos[5].val();
```

And if I log the bulk in console, the data appears correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I declared the "bulk" array like this:

```
var bulk = {};
bulk['graduados'] = {};
bulk['nacimientos'] = {};
bulk['puestos'] = {};
bulk['incorporaciones'] = {};
```

instead of:

```
var bulk = new Array();
bulk['graduados'] = new Array();
bulk['nacimientos'] = new Array();
bulk['puestos'] = new Array();
bulk['incorporaciones'] = new Array();
```

I don't know the exact reason behind this, maybe I can't pass full arrays using ajax, but objects are accepted correctly...